Why is Task.Run() blocking controller action when handling long-running CPU-bound Tasks?
I'm working on an .NET 6 Web API and handling a CPU-bound task using Task.Run() to offload it to a background thread. However, it seems like my controller action is still being blocked, and the request is not returning immediately as expected.
Code Example:
[HttpGet("process-data")]
public IActionResult ProcessData()
{
    Task.Run(() => LongRunningTask());
    
    return Ok("Processing started...");
}

private void LongRunningTask()
{
    // Simulating a long CPU-bound task
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    // Further processing...
}


My questions are:

Why is Task.Run() not allowing the controller action to return immediately?
What’s the correct way to run a CPU-bound task in the background while returning an immediate response in an ASP.NET Core Web API?
Is there a better approach to handling CPU-bound tasks asynchronously in ASP.NET Core?

I used Task.Run() to offload the CPU-bound work to a background thread, but the controller action still blocks until the task finishes. I expect the response Processing started... to be returned immediately while the long-running task executes in the background. Instead, the request seems to be blocked until the LongRunningTask() completes.

You should take a look at hosted services, especially queued background tasks. FYI Thread != Task, a single thread can execute multiple tasks. Task.Run does not guarantee that your task is offloaded to another thread and should not be used for CPU bound work.

@​​MindSwipe "Task.Run does not guarantee that your task is offloaded to another thread and should not be used for CPU bound work." -- Citation? Is this your opinion, common wisdom, Microsoft knowledge base, what?  Please consider posting your comment as an answer, so that it can be vetted appropriately by the community. Comments cannot be downvoted, and are not intended for answering the question.

"Instead, the request seems to be blocked until the LongRunningTask() completes." -- How did you come to this conclusion? What kind of experiment did you conduct that validate this hypothesis?

Why do you use the GET verb to initiate an asynchronous job? IMHO POST would be more appropriate.


Is this the actual code that you are executing? Are you using any await or .Wait()? This code should execute LongRunningTask() on thread pool which will run it in another thread and it should not block your request thread.
Task.Run is ok, but if this endpoint is called too frequently or LongRunningTask is too long, it may starve the thread pool, which will throttle your incoming requests. In those cases it is better to control the processing of long running tasks in a Background service using a queue.

You may also use return Accepted(); //HTTP code 202 instead of Ok() //200 (200 is also fine), as Accepted indicates asynchronous operation / background task.

Also this should not be GET request, it's rather is POST
